# Issue wtih urls returned in JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm using Alamofire to make the requests to an API Restful and SwiftyJSON to handle the JSON response, in the following way :

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlTo, parameters: params, encoding: .URL).responseString(completionHandler: {
         (request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, 
          responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

   var response = self.stripHtmlTags(responseBody!)

   // Parse the response to NSData
   if let data = (response as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        println(json)
   }
})
```

But I've an issue with the urls returned in the JSON, are returned in the following way :

```
"url_image" : "path1\/path2\/path3\/path4\/path5\/p\/1342.jpg"
```

I can format it, but I would like to know if it's something with the encoding passes to Alamofire or something else and how can I fix it.

Any help is very appreciatted.

Answer (score 0):

An unsafe method but it will work in your case is to get rid of all backslashes (). Take the URL and remove the backslashes, and then use that as a URL path to append to your URL. Because they are paths, consecutive backslashes probably won't happen here so just do a replace for all backslashes.

Comment: I know I can format it, please read my question, but I want to know why this happens?

Comment: @VictorSigler this happens because they insert backslashes to delimit potentially unsafe characters. If I had a string and I had a quote in the string, I would need to delimit that character, like "somestring\"something".